# Unable to connect to BF1 servers

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-1

The problem is simple yet I have done a quick google search and no one else seems to be having this issue. I am playing on XBox 1 and when attempting to join servers, the screen reverts back to the server menu.

For example, when I attempt to directly join a server, the game does not get past the "loading game" screen. Instead, after a moment or two on that screen, it reverts back to the server browser screen. There is no error message and it does not seem to be a network issue on my end.

It does not work through quickplay as well.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you play any other multiplayer games on the console? Also, did you install all the patches?

Comment: Have seen those kind of issues in CS:GO when server and client don't have the same game version. This could also be your case. *PS: as BF1 servers are not mantained by particulars, it'd be a client side issue, so try checking for updates*

Comment: Is your XBox 1 and BF1 updated to the latest patches?